# uploaded file differ with the original

Tags: node.js, http

I'm trying to upload a file with node using this simple code:

```
UpdateController.prototype.uploadUpdateFile = function(req, res)
{
    var w = fs.createWriteStream(settings.uploadFolder + settings.updateFile);
    req.pipe(w);
    w.on('finish', function()
    {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            status:0,
            filename:settings.uploadFolder + settings.updateFile
        }));
    }, function()
    {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            status:1,
            message:"error during file upload, operation failed"
        }));
    });
}
```

The file is correctly uploaded but it changes between the original because header (------WebKitForm ... /octet-stream....) and footer (..------WebKitFormBoundary9gOZjMubs9GivcUQ--..) are added to the content.

How to get only the file content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to look at the headers of the client request to understand how the client decided to send you the file (how the file was encoded)

You will probably end up using busboy or another package that depends on it : https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy

such a package will "decode" the data sent by the browser.